# How to take values out of if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

At the moment I am trying to build a program that generates a quiz of random numbers with set operations and asks you to solve to earn points. I set each question with an if else statement where the correct answer gives 25 and the wrong gives 0. However when I try to add these numbers up from outside the if else statement the program does not recognize they have a value set to them already. any help would be apperciated and here is a transcript of the code i have so far
package osu.cse1223;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Project03a {


public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your name");
String Name = keyboard.next();
System.out.println("Hello " + Name + "!");
int upper = 100;
int lower = 10;
int i = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
System.out.println(i);
int a = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
int b = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
int ab = a + b;
int c = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
int d = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
int cd = c - d;
int e = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
int f = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
int ef = e/f;
int g = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
int h = (int) ((Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower);
int gh = g%h;
int finala = 0;
if (i%2 ==  0) {
    System.out.println("quiz one");
    System.out.println("Question 1: " + a + "+" + b);
    int answera = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (answera == ab) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
            int totala = 25;
            int finalb = finala + totala;
            System.out.println(finalb);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
            int totala = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("Question 2: " + c + "-" + d);
        int answerb = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (answerb == cd) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                int totalb = 25;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Incorrect");
            }
        System.out.println("Question 3:" + e + "/" + f);
            int answerc = keyboard.nextInt();
              if (answerc == ef){
                  System.out.println("Correct!");
                  int totalc = 25;
              }else{
                  System.out.println("Incorrect :(");
              }
        System.out.println("Question 4:" + g + "%" + h);
        int answerd = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (answerd == gh){
                 System.out.println("Correct!");
                  int totald = 25;
            }else{ System.out.println("Incorrect :(");
            }
            int score = totala + totalb + totalc +totald;
    }else{
    System.out.println("quiz two");
```

}

Comment: you have to declare the variables totala, totalb ecc.. out of the if, this code won't compile

Answer (score 3):

Here, `totala`, `totalb`, `totalc`, `totald` are declared locally. When you declare a variable it will be accessible inside the block, and not outside.

**There are two ways:**

You can declare and initialize `totala`, `totalb`, `totalc`, `totald` before the beginning of the quiz (at the same level as `a`, `b`, `c`).

**OR**

You can keep your variable `finala` (and find a better name like `score`), and use it in the 4 blocks to add the result.

Answer (score 1):

A declaration like

```
int totala = 0;
```

declares the variable for use *only* in the smallest scope in which it's enclosed, often the nearest curly braces `{` .. `}`.  So here:

```
else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect");
    int totala = 0;
}
```

`totala` can be used only within these two curly braces, and if you declare `int totala` inside some other scope, that's a *different* variable entirely.

To declare a `totala` that you can use in more than one place, declare

```
int totala;
```

inside the `main` method but *outside* any other set of curly braces.  Then leave out the word `int` when assigning it:

```
else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect");
    totala = 0;  // will set the totala that you declared outside
}
```

(**P.S.:** Although the smallest scope is often the nearest curly braces, it's different for a `for` statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something; i++) some-statement;

for (int i = 0; i < something; i++) { ... }
```

The `int i` declares an `i` that can be used inside the parenthesized first part of the `for`, and inside the statement or group of statements that you're looping, but nowhere else.  There are other special cases.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this advice finally got me moving in the right direction again!! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize totala and finalb with the rest of your variables and manipulate them inside the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code has to do with the range of your variables.

When you declare a variable in an if for example. The variable will only exist in the range of the if.

```
if(answer == ab)
{
  int i = 0;

}
```

The Variable i  will only exist in the if loop.